# Remember own LaTeX commands

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

In my LaTeX writings I always use the same abbreviated commands, since many years. For example, I use "\z" for "\langle" and "\x" for "\rangle", or "\fr" for "\displaystyle\frac", and so on..

Is it possible to implement a solution that remembers the user's own additional LaTeX commands somehow? (Or maybe such feature does already exist?)

Comment: Not yet available. I proposed something similar [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6458/1543). Something like this will almost certainly necessitate the loading of the `begingroup` extension.

Comment: What?  `\z` `\x`?  But then you don't get to say "langle rangle" in your head whenever you generate a subgroup.

Comment: @Berci for `\displaystyle\frac` you could use `\dfrac`

Comment: I have asked about solutions which could serve as a workaround if this is not implemented: [Is there some way to include some default text quickly in a post?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31231)